# Image manipulation with gifs in discord.js - jimp does not support, so how else would i do it?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, bots, discord, discord.js

im trying to manipulate a gif now, but I cant use jimp, can anyone possible give me an example of what I could use to composite a still and a gif together?
I've created one with jimp but not with any gifs - only pngs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the watermark feature on [gifshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifshot). Then you could do:

```js
gifshot.createGIF({
  'images': ['https://i.imgur.com/6LWF4Cj.gif'],
  waterMark: 'http://i.imgur.com/GDDN1l9.jpg'
},function(obj) {
  if(!obj.error) {
    var image = obj.image;
    // do something with image
  }
});
```

Edit: Nevermind looks like it's client-side only...